# List index out of range

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am new to python and ros and i am trying to get to different goals defined by me but I get the error: list imdex out of range and i dont know why because as far as i know, the list index is not out of range.
my code is below and also the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import math
from std_msgs.msg import String
from std_msgs.msg import Int32
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist          # Import the Twist message from the geometry_msgs
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan       # Import the LaserScan message from the sensor
from gazebo_msgs.msg import ModelStates  #import ModelState message from gazebo_msgs
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose,Point         # Import the Pose message from the geometry_msgs
from tf.transformations import euler_from_quaternion
from goal_publisher.msg import PointArray
from math import pow, atan2, sqrt


PI= 3.1415926535897
repeat = 0
theta = 0.0
x = 0.0
y = 0.0
msg = 0.0
index_same=0.0
target = 90
kp=0.5

class MovetoGoals:
    def __init__(self):

        # Creates a node with name 'final_projekt_node' and make sure it is a
        # unique node (using anonymous=True).
        rospy.init_node('final_projekt_node', anonymous=True)

        # Publisher which will publish to the topic 'Twist'.
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel',Twist, queue_size=10)

        # A subscriber to the topic 'Modelstate'. self.update_pose is called
        # when a message of type Pose is received.
        self.pose_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/gazebo/model_states',ModelStates, self.update_pose)
        self.goals_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/goals',PointArray,self.get_goals)
        self.dist_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/distance',Int32,self.distance_tracker)
        self.laser_sub = rospy.Subscriber('scan', LaserScan,self.detect_obstacle)# subscriber to subscribe to laser messages
        self.pose = ModelStates()
        self.current_distance = Int32()
        self.the_goals = PointArray()
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(10)

    def update_pose(self, data):
        """Callback function which is called when a new message of type Pose is
        received by the subscriber."""
        #print('in update_pose function')

        self.pose = data
        self.pose.pose[1].position.x = round(self.pose.pose[1].position.x, 4)
        self.pose.pose[1].position.y = round(self.pose.pose[1].position.y, 4)

        #print ('robots x position' self.pose.pose[1].position.x)

    def euclidean_distance(self,goal_pose):

        return sqrt(pow((goal_pose.x - self.pose.pose[1].position.x), 2) +
                    pow((goal_pose.y - self.pose.pose[1].position.y), 2))

    def linear_vel(self,goal_pose, constant=1):

        #return constant * (self.euclidean_distance(goal_pose))
        return abs(1.0)

    def steering_angle(self, goal_pose):

        return atan2(goal_pose.y - self.pose.pose[1].position.y,goal_pose.x - self.pose.pose[1].position.x)

    def angular_vel(self,goal_pose, constant=2):

        global theta
        self.pose.pose[1].orientation = self.pose.pose[1].orientation
        (roll, pitch, theta) = euler_from_quaternion([self.pose.pose[1].orientation.x, self.pose.pose[1].orientation.y, self.pose.pose[1].orientation.z, self.pose.pose[1].orientation.w])
        #print ('theta at update pose is', + theta)
        #print ('theta is', + theta)
        return constant * (self.steering_angle(goal_pose) - theta)
        #return 0.3

    def get_goals(self,the_goals):
        global x
        global y
        x = the_goals.goals[0].x
        y = the_goals.goals[0].y
        #print x
        #print y

    def distance_tracker(self,distance):
        self.current_distance = distance.data


    def detect_obstacle(self,laser_msg):
        global msg
        msg = laser_msg.ranges[0]
        #index_same = all(ele == laser_msg.ranges[0] for ele in laser_msg.ranges[0:10])

    #function to rotate robot approx. 90 degrees
    def rotate(self):
        vel_msg = Twist()
        print("in rotate function")
        speed = 30
        angle = 90
        angular_speed = speed*2*PI/360
        relative_angle = angle*2*PI/360

        vel_msg.linear.x=0
        vel_msg.linear.y=0
        vel_msg.linear.z=0
        vel_msg.angular.x = 0
        vel_msg.angular.y = 0

        vel_msg.angular.z = -abs(angular_speed)

        t0 = rospy.Time.now().to_sec()
        current_angle = 0

        while(current_angle < relative_angle):
            self.pub.publish(vel_msg)
            t1 = rospy.Time.now().to_sec()
            current_angle = angular_speed*(t1-t0)

        vel_msg.angular.z = 0
        self.pub.publish(vel_msg)

    def move2goal(self):
        """Moves the turtle to the goal."""
        goal_pose = Point()
        #goal_pose.x = input("Set your x goal: ")
        #goal_pose.y = input("Set your y goal: ")
        goal_pose.x = 3.5
        goal_pose.y = 9.0


        # Please, insert a number slightly greater than 0 (e.g. 0.01).
        distance_tolerance = 0.1

        vel_msg = Twist()

        while True:
            if self.euclidean_distance(goal_pose) >= distance_tolerance and msg > 1.5:
                print msg
                print self.current_distance

                # Linear velocity in the x-axis.
                vel_msg.linear.x = self.linear_vel(goal_pose)
                vel_msg.linear.y = 0
                vel_msg.linear.z = 0

                # Angular velocity in the z-axis.
                vel_msg.angular.x = 0
                vel_msg.angular.y = 0
                vel_msg.angular.z = self.angular_vel(goal_pose)

            elif self.euclidean_distance(goal_pose) < distance_tolerance and msg > 1.5:
                print('goal reached')
                break

            else:
                print('obstacle detected')
                vel_msg.linear.x = 0
                #target_rad = target*math.pi/180
                #vel_msg.linear.z = kp*(target_rad-theta)
                self.rotate()

                # Publishing our vel_msg

            self.pub.publish(vel_msg)


            # Publish at the desired rate.
            self.rate.sleep()

            # Stopping our robot after the movement is over.
        print('stopping robot')
        vel_msg.linear.x = 0
        vel_msg.angular.z = 0
        self.pub.publish(vel_msg)

        rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        object = MovetoGoals()
        object.move2goal()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

The error is:

```
core service [/rosout] found
process[final_projekt_node-1]: started with pid [17840]
process[goal_publisher-2]: started with pid [17841]
process[track-3]: started with pid [17842]
[INFO] [1560706012.005172, 0.000000]: Configuration file name: config.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amr/catkin_ws/src/oe-161016_tier4/oe_161016_prj/src/turtle_sim.py", line 207, in <module>
    object.move2goal()
  File "/home/amr/catkin_ws/src/oe-161016_tier4/oe_161016_prj/src/turtle_sim.py", line 143, in move2goal
    if self.euclidean_distance(goal_pose) >= distance_tolerance and msg > 1.5:
  File "/home/amr/catkin_ws/src/oe-161016_tier4/oe_161016_prj/src/turtle_sim.py", line 61, in euclidean_distance
    return sqrt(pow((goal_pose.x - self.pose.pose[1].position.x), 2) +
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The [structure of the ModelStates topic](http://docs.ros.org/api/gazebo_msgs/html/msg/ModelStates.html)
So the list is made up of more different positions and orientations of obejects in the gazebo world, like the robot e.t.c and I did `rostopic echo` to make sure and i got this

```
pose: 
  
    position: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  
    position: 
      x: -3.40717160297e-05
      y: 9.40266793714e-05
      z: -0.00100139287064
    orientation: 
      x: -9.90025971612e-06
      y: 0.00385309557022
      z: 0.000737195142211
      w: 0.99999230502
twist: 
  
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  
    linear: 
      x: 7.42159494544e-08
      y: 6.63937672672e-07
      z: 3.5974708812e-05
    angular: 
      x: 3.90254538909e-05
      y: -0.000180313959702
      z: 9.82618596517e-06
```

so please, how is the list index out of range?

The error is in def euclidean_distance.

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326034/list-index-out-of-range/) by [Jojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/42284/jojo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-06-17**:
Please make sure to use the *preformatted text* (`101010`) button when posting code or terminal output. It makes your question **much** easier to read when you use it

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-06-17**:
What topic are you showing exactly? Can you please update your question with the output of

rostopic echo /gazebo/model_states

with just one message of the topic printed? Something doesn't look right because when I do it, i get

```
name: [ground_plane]
pose: 
  - 
    position: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
twist: 
  - 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
```

notice the `-` in there which is YAML syntax for a list.

**Comment by [Jojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/42284/jojo/) on 2019-06-20**:
Thank you for edting my question and the tips on posting a code here.
I have solved the problem with the answer given below.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-06-20**:
If that answered your question, then please click the to the left of the answer to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to allow some time for poses to be received from Gazebo before you try to use them. Although you set up the subscriber for `/gazebo/model_states` in the `MovetoGoals` object's constructor, you do not give ROS any time to receive anything on the topic before you start calling `move2goal` which internally via the `euclidean_distance` function tries to use the value that will be set by `update_pose`. This means that `update_pose` has not yet been called when `euclidean_distance` is called so it tries to access a pose in the empty `ModelStates` object's array.

To solve this, you need to give some time to ROS to receive the data you want to use before you start trying to send movement commands based on received data. Add a function that allows ROS to receive a few methods (e.g. creating a rate object of 10 Hz and doing a `rate.sleep()` on it) until you see that the size of the ModelStates object has data.

Also make sure that the second pose in the list is the one you want. In Python, list indices are zero-based.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2019-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/42284/jojo/) on 2019-06-20**:
Solved it .Thanks